Can a Blazor Wasm application be deployed in a subdomain?
Situation:
The owner of a domain has asked me to write some applications.
Currently they have a static website running on their main domain (like https://www.MyWebsite.com) and some different static websites running on subdomains, like intranet.mywebsite.com, admin.mywebsite.com, and so on.
The applications on the subdomain need to be gobbled up into one application, and it needs to become an interactive webapplication.
I have developed a blazor wasm application with an api (blazor server isn't possible because you need to be able to define a server farm, and the assets are not available for that), and the idea was to put it in on of the subdomains and run it.
It's not a subapplication (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/host-and-deploy/iis/advanced?view=aspnetcore-8.0#sub-applications), and I have no access (they want to keep both seperated) to the static website anyway.
Area information are always refering to a blazor server application.
I have difficulty finding the appropriate information, and I'm not even sure if it is possible anyway.
The application will be deployed on IIS and windows server.
till now, no actual roll-out had been attempted****

Yes, you can interact with them using application request routing, more information you can refer to this link: Reverse Proxy with URL Rewrite v2 and Application Request Routing.

Although I'm still failing to deploy, I took the counter sample standalone wasm appliation and deployed that one to the subdomain. Regular deployment, add website in IIS, added certificate, filled in the name of the url like subdomainname.domainname.com (same forn the application pool) and it basically worked. There was no rewrite 'n' stuff needed, no configuring of the base-tag, and so one.
So my deployment failure issue is not due to letting it host on a subdomain. Basically there is no difference between deploying a stand-alone-app to a main domain or to a subdomain as far as I can figure out.
